# JavaFX TextArea - Unwanted scroll listeners

Tags: java, scroll, javafx, textarea

I've written an override of the TextArea class of the JavaFX library.

The point is that I want to use the directional keys for my own listeners but, when I try to use the directional keys **up** or **down**, they automatically scrolls the textarea up or down.
I want to disable this function but I don't know how.
I already searched the net for answers but I didn't find anything related to this.

Can someone help me? (Please apologize me if I wrote bad because I'm not english)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an [EventFilter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#addEventFilter-javafx.event.EventType-javafx.event.EventHandler-) and consume the events.